# Combining data from different data.frames in ggplot2 with unexpected results

Tags: r, ggplot2

Suppose we have the following data.frames:

```
dt1 <- data.frame(x=1:10,y=rnorm(10),g="a",c=1)
dt2 <- data.frame(x=1:10,y=rnorm(10),g="b",c=2)
dt <- rbind(dt1,dt2)

bb <- data.frame(x=1:4,y=rep(-5,4))
```

The following works

```
qplot(x=x,y=y,data=dt,group=g,colour=c)+geom_line(aes(x=bb$x,y=bb$y),colour="black")
```

producing additional black line with data from data.frame `bb`. But with

```
bb <- data.frame(x=1:6,y=rep(-5,6))
```

the same plotting code fails with a complaint that number of rows is different. I could merge the data.frames, i.e. expand `bb` with NAs, but I thought that the code above is valid ggplot2 code, albeit not exactly in spirit of it. So the question is why it fails? (The answer is probably related to the fact that 4 divides 20, when 6 does not, but more context would be desirable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify different data sets to use in different layers:

```
qplot(x=x,y=y,data=dt,group=g,colour=c) + 
  geom_line(aes(x=x, y=y, group=NULL, colour=NULL), data=bb, colour="black")
```

Here, `geom_line` uses the data from `bb` rather than `dt`.  Instead of using a mixture of `qplot` and `geom` specifications, here it is in pure `ggplot` notation:

```
ggplot(data = dt, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point(aes(group = g, colour = c)) +
  geom_line(data=bb, colour="black")
```

Comment: Supplying different data set did not work. The key here is supplying group and colour NULL values with new data set. Strange that pure ggplot works as expected, but qplot does not.

Comment: It is not strange, the `ggplot` call only defines `x` and `y` aesthetics (which become the defaults for the plot).

Answer (score 2):

The code does not work for me with your first definition of bb too (ggplot2_0.9.2.1):

```
Error: Aesthetics must either be length one, or the same length as the dataProblems:bb$x, bb$y
```

This works:

```
p1 <- ggplot(data=dt,aes(x=x,y=y,group=g,colour=factor(c)))+geom_line()
p1 + geom_line(data=bb,aes(group=0,colour=factor(0))) +
      scale_colour_manual(values = c("black","blue","red"))
```

Comment: Thanks, the key here was supplying group and colour values. Both answers were helpful, sorry I had to chose one.

Comment: I am sorry, but I am not following this discussion at all. The error says that Aesthetic (aes) "must either be length one or the same length as the data". What data needs to be the same length as what other data? And what are group and colour values doing to accomplish this? Or is the error message misleading?